# Unpivot two columns and group by cohorts

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have a table with 5 columns:

- Cohorts (NULL, 1, 2, 3, 4)
- Status (0,1)
- Emails
- Week_Number (Emails who logged in during that week)
- Week_Number2 (Emails from Week_Number who logged in during Week_Number2)

**My main query yields something like that:**

```
+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| cohort | status |     email     | week_number | week_number2 |
+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| null   |      0 | aaa@email.com |           5 | 6            |
| 1      |      1 | bbb@email.com |           5 | 6            |
| 1      |      1 | ccc@email.com |           5 | 6            |
| 2      |      0 | ddd@email.com |           5 | NULL         |
| 3      |      1 | eee@email.com |           5 | 6            |
| 3      |      0 | fff@email.com |          5  | 6            |
| 4      |      0 | ggg@gmail.com |           5 | NULL         |
+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
```

**Objective:**

Basically I would like to group the results by cohorts, status and have both weeks under
one column and add column for the total count.
My output should show the following:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| cohort | status | week        | total_count |
+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| null   |      0 |           5 |           1 |
| null   |      0 |           6 |           1 |
| 1      |      1 |           5 |           2 |
| 1      |      1 |           6 |           2 |
| 2      |      0 |           5 |           1 |
| 3      |      0 |           5 |           1 |
| 3      |      0 |           6 |           1 |
| 3      |      1 |           5 |           1 |
| 3      |      1 |           6 |           1 |
| 4      |      0 |           5 |           1 |
+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

My query which gives me the first output is:

```
SELECT 
     t3.Cohort
    ,t3.[Status]
    ,t1.Email
    ,t1.Week_Number
    ,t2.Week_Number2
FROM #table     AS t1     -- Gets first week info
LEFT JOIN #table2   AS t2 -- Gets second week info
    ON t1.Email=t2.Email
LEFT JOIN #table3   AS t3 -- Gets status and cohort
    ON t1.Email=t3.Email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `apply` to unpivot the data.  Then you seem to want aggregation:

```
select t.Cohort, t3.[Status], v.week, count(*)
from #table t cross apply
     (values (t.Week_Number), (t.Week_Number2)) v(week)
where v.week is not null
group by t.Cohort, t3.[Status], v.week;
```

Comment: that works beautifully. why did you choose cross apply instead of unpivot ?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . `apply` is a general purpose operator that implements a lateral join.  Lateral joins are quite powerful and have many uses.  `unpivot` is arcane syntax to do one thing, and -- frankly -- `apply` even does that better in my opinion.